# Can every one variable equation be solved without graphing?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Can every one variable equation be solved without graphing?

How would you solve the following without graphing:

$$3y + 4\sqrt{1-y^2} = 2$$

Comment: Group, square both sides, solve, eliminate spurious solutions, if any.

Comment: Your equation *can* be solved without graphing. For one that *can't*, a nice example is $$x^2=2^x$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But how does graphing that "solve" it?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ohh, and it is fairly straightforward to show that it will have precisely two solutions by considering derivatives. And since these are in integers, no graphing will be needed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - When you say solving by graphing, you mean get an estimate of whether there's a solution or not? Because newton's method would be a better way to get an approx solution if that's what is wanted.

Comment: @Tobias 3 solutions, in fact

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What is the third?

Comment: @spandan I made a leap and assumed that "solve by graphing" refers to any approximate solution method.

Comment: @Tobias there must be a negative solution (by the intermediate value theorem). Of course, finding that root requires investigating the function's behavior on the negative side.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ahh, good point, so that is at least a hard to find solution (not that graphing really helps with that either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We see $$3y-2=-4\sqrt{1-y^2}$$
so $$(3y-2)^2=16-16y^2$$
therefore $$9y^2-12y+4=16-16y^2$$
rearranging gives $$25y^2-12y-12=0$$
And so the solutions are $$y_0,y_1=\frac{12}{50}\pm\frac{1}{50}\sqrt{144+1200}$$
and simplifying yields $$y_0,y_1=\frac{6\pm4\sqrt{21}}{25}$$
Checking these solutions will give us the unique solution $$y_0=\frac{6-4\sqrt{21}}{25}$$

Comment: Isn't the initial starting equation incorrect?

Comment: Excuse me, @Arjun. Fixed it.

Comment: The above equation was obtained by rearranging the pythagorean theorem for the unit circle to get a value for $sinx$ in terms of $cos^2x$, and then substituting the expression as y into $3sinx + 4cosx = 2$. Do you know why the double angle identity along with a coefficient in front is used rather than this method to turn an equation with two trig functions into an equivalent one with one trig function?

Comment: To be a bit tedious, I think you should check that those solutions are in $\left[-1,\frac23\right]$, because the "so" in your third line is an "if and only if" if and only if $3y-2\le 0$ and $1-y^2\ge 0$.

Comment: @Gae.S., you're completely right. My steps are no equivalence (that is, I cannot do them in reverse order) and so I needed to verify my solutions. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One canonical example of an equation of one variable that can't be solved without graphing is
$$ x^2=e^x.$$
Try it for yourself if you'd like.

Comment: How does graphing this "solve" it?